# Protecting the bottom of the wall while painting vinyl siding

Tags: painting, exterior, protection

I will be painting my vinyl siding in order to change the color.  Below the bottom row of siding, there's a sort of a flexible white strip tucked into place.  I'm not sure, maybe this is called flashing.  Anyway, the strip is maybe 8 to 10 inches wide.  That would be a LOT of masking tape to cover it to protect from drips and splashes.  Is there some easier way to protect it?  I don't particularly want to paint it.  The white will coordinate with the window trim and the door and with my grayish light blue new siding color, I think it will look cheerful.  Which is the whole point of this painting project, as the house is currently a depressing drab light brown color, which looks especially bad next to a taller house that is lemon yellow.

Comment: *Painting Vinyl Siding - What Can Go Wrong* – [house-design-coffee.com](https://www.house-design-coffee.com/painting-vinyl-siding.html)

Answer (score 1):

Mask it off, we used brown paper (1m or 40" wide approx) to cover larger areas like your flashing strip. We had 2" masking tape for that paper and 1" masking tape to sort tiny detail.

Comment: They sell this in widths perfect for the OP too.

Comment: Do I lay out a section of paper on a table and put the masking tape on it, and then carry it over to the wall to tape it on?  Otherwise I feel like I'd have to be an octopus.

Comment: We used to pre-tape sections of paper for some areas - tight etc But we also had a paper roll holder which would automatically add tape to the edge as you pulled the paper off you wanted.

Comment: The paper tape holder that Mike refers to takes 12" wide rolls of paper.  It's not like you're wielding this contraption with 40" wide paper...

Comment: @JPhi1618 I was masking paper making machines to spary them - using 12" would be like using toilet paper... The sprayers we used had an 12" fan...

Comment: For one small house, a special applicator seems like overkill.  Hmm.  I wish they would sell a roll of paper with something stick on one edge, like post-its.