# Would folded 2" green masking tape protect the foundation covering?

Tags: painting, preparation

Related question: [Protecting the bottom of the wall while painting vinyl siding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/162581/74694)

I have some 2" wide green masking tape.  I am wondering if the following would be enough protection of the white strip that covers the foundation (below the siding): put down about three feet of the tape but without putting pressure along the bottom, then grasp both ends and fold the whole length of tape up, to make an L-shaped profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A painter friend convinced me not to protect this thing, which he called "flashing."  The bottom row of siding sticks out more than the flashing, so with a bit of care I can paint the siding without swiping the top of the flashing.  I tried it and it worked well.